# Build API with ASP.NET Web API on Django project

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc, django, asp.net-web-api, django-rest-framework

We are currently building our event management platform at a company i work for, The authentication service is being built with ASP.NET identity framework.

The main event management platform is built in Django using python, which i have built.

We are also planning on building a custom admin portal in ASP.NET MVC,
which will manage users and event data.

The problem is that the C# guys(Who are contractors albeit very experienced developers) want to build out the API using ASP.NET for the event app which is built in django, using the Database first model that .NET provides, thus the database migrations will be handled by Django, but the actual API will be built using ASP.NETS Web API, directly from the database.

This approach does not seem to make much sense in my opinion as it would  make a lot more sense to build out the the API using Django rest framework and manage the database migrations for the event app. Instead of tightly coupling the database with Web API.

Either way both approaches are are effectively doing the same thing, but i don't think it's efficient to constantly manage two environments, migrations in one environment and api management in the other, this does not allow for flexibility.

What are the potential disadvantages of the WEB API approach.

Comment: If you're building an API what does it matter what its written in? You consume it the same way